Process typescript module type
I have a babel extension which process files with extension .ext.ts. I cannot explain to typescript then any module with this extension is not of type T, initially detected, but
type Correct<T> = {[K in keyof T]: Fixed<T[K]>}

I think here must help declare module "*.ext.ts", but I don't have the path of module to import the autodetected type.
Thanks in advice.
